# Delete user when profile and Company has deleted

Tags: django, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I have the following model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  bedrijf = models.ForeignKey(Bedrijf, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Bedrijf(models.Model):
  bedrijfsnaam = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)  
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
    n = Bedrijf.objects.create(bedrijfsnaam="Gaarne_bedrijfsnaam_instellen")
    n.save()
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance, bedrijf=n)
```

I want to delete the User when Bedrijf has been deleted. With this config the profile will be deleted but not the User. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a post_delete signal like this:

```
# Delete User after Profile (chained with Bedrijf) has been deleted
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Profile)
def delete_user_after_profile_delete(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    instance.user.delete()
```